# How to convert SQL to JPQL (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**How to convert SQL to JPQL in Springboot.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably better to put the query here in text rather than an image, also maybe add some details about what you have tried so far with code examples.

Comment: After the query , put  nativeQuery = true like this -> @Query("some query",  nativeQuery = true)